# List files inside a folder unless the absolute path

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I want to write a script that lists all the files I have within a folder.

My try:

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! test -d "$1" ; then
  echo `pwd`/$1
else
  cd "$1"
for f in * ; do
  "$0" "$f"
done
fi
```

I invoke: `sh /home/user/test.sh folder`.

This script works only if I specify the absolute path of the script. I'm looking for a more general solution that works also if I specify the script relative path.

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't work if you do `sh test.sh folder`? I can't see why that would make a difference.

Comment: BTW, you should be consistent about which shell you want to use for the script. If the script has `#!/bin/bash` then you should use `bash test.sh folder`

Comment: What error do you get if you use a relative path?

Comment: A lot to comment here. What is wrong with `ls -R *` ? ...(Next) .... `sh /some/scriptname` is a bad habit to get into. You already have `#!/bin/bash` as your first line. Good show!. ...,,, If it doesn't work when you type `./test.sh`, then `chmod +x ./test.sh`. ...... I am having to guess about what the output of your script looks like: `/path/to/file;/path/to/file2/;...`? (sub `;` with line break). ..... Running "`pwd`" is expensive, `$PWD` holds the same info but is a lot faster. Good luck.

Comment: The problem is that the relative path to the script is no longer valid after you change directories with `cd "$1"`.

Comment: Why not just `find "$1" -type f` to print all filenames recursively?

Comment: If I don't run with the absolute path I get "test.sh: no such file"

Comment: The script looks like some recursive listing of all file system objects except directories, similar to `find $(realpath folder) ! -type d`. Is this for learning shell programming? Please [edit] your question and show an example of the directories and files and the expected output. Show the output of `pwd` and the invocation of your script that does not work and the resulting output. Please add all information to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the string-line solution inside the comments or write another script where you:

- pre-process the input
- add the full path
- then invoke the script

To do that, create another script `test-rec.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
if test "$0" = /* ; then
  echo "Absolute path"
  rec_cmd="`dirname "$0"`/test.sh"
elif test "$0" = */* ; then
  echo "Relative path"
  rec_cmd="`pwd`/`dirname "$0"`/test.sh"
else
  echo "Neither absolute or relative, I use the PATH"
  rec_cmd="test.sh"
fi
"$rec_cmd" "$1"
```

to be invoked in the same way, through `sh test-rec.sh folder`

Comment: `if "$0" = /*` that is just invalid, it will execute command `$0` with arguments `= /bin /etc....`. If you want to check if a string matches a glob expression, use `case`. In bash, you can also use very special `[[`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this. It's short sweet and simple. The script lists the content when called from a directory.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Determine the current directory
current_dir="$PWD"

# List all files and directories within the current directory
ls -la "$current_dir"
```

If you want to list files only from the current directory.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Determine the current directory
current_dir="$PWD"

# List only the files within the current directory
find "$current_dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec basename {} \;
```

In this script, the find command is used with the **-exec** option to execute the basename command on each file found. The basename command extracts and prints the filename from the path. By using the **-exec** option, we can achieve the desired result of listing only the filenames.

Please note, this is on **macOS other systems the exact commands may vary**.

If you want to call the script from any directory without stating the path you can use the find command to locate the script. **Save as run_script** and **add the script to a suitable directory included in the $PATH variable.** You can add additional scripts into the **run_scripts** code and call them by using the script's name as an argument. However, this is overkill for the task you are trying to complete and ***could potentially cause issues if you are not cearful.*** Either way, the shell needs a path to locate the script.

A better approach would be to learn how to add custom functions to the $fpath variable and create a function to achieve the same result.

> https://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/51-using-fpath-path-together.html

> https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33255/how-to-define-and-load-your-own-shell-function-in-zsh

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the script name from the argument
script_name="$1"

# Check if a script name is provided
if [[ -z "$script_name" ]]; then
  echo "Please provide a script name."
  exit 1
fi

# Search for the script from the current directory
script_path=$(find . -name "$script_name" -type f -print -quit)

# Check if the script was found
if [[ -n "$script_path" ]]; then
  # Extract the directory path from the script's path
  script_dir=$(dirname "$script_path")

  # Change to the script's directory
  cd "$script_dir" || exit

  # Call the script using its relative path
  ./"$script_name"
else
  echo "Script not found."
fi
```

Call your script by using `./run-scripts script` and the run-scripts script will search for the specified script and execute it if found.

Comment: "`script_path=$(find . -name "$script_name" -type f -print -quit)`" , yes, you can do that, but because you're starting at `.` it could be that you won't find the script. Not a good recommendation. All users of terminal programs (shells, and the OS utilities available there) need to learn about the env var PATH, how to check it, append new dirs and where it is set in the `.login` and `.bash_rc` etc files where it may be being overwritten. They should also know about skipping the need for using `PATH` by providing `/full/path/to/script` and `./myScript, `and `./relative/path/to/script.`GoodLuck

Comment: @shellter I totally agree, but appending a suitable location to the $PATH variable and putting the run_script script there, is how I call a number of my scripts. I have modified the answer to include a warning, stating that there is "potential for issues" if not careful". The answer was to demonstrate that a script needs the path, one way or another to run. Thank you for bringing that up.

Comment: @shellter I didn't suggest searching the entire root directory ("/") because it can be a time-consuming operation, especially if the filesystem is large. I was going with the script being saved under the home directory, but again I agree with what you are saying and I will be sure to present better answers. Thank you for your critiques.

Comment: yes, I think we understand each other. Writing "improvements" in comments isn't ideal. Good luck to all!

Answer (score 0):

If you change directories with `cd` then the relative path will break because it's relative to where you started.

Instead, you can stay in your current directory and append the relative path to each file (`for f in "$1"/*`). That way you preserve the relative path to your script, and find your files and directories by *their* relative paths instead of assuming they're in your current working directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! test -d "$1" ; then
  echo "$PWD"/"$1"
else
  for f in "$1"/* ; do
    "$0" "$f"
  done
fi
```

But of course, this seems needlessly complicated. There are lots of tools that can do what you're trying to do here without recursive script calls. For example: `find "$PWD"/folder ! -type d` will recursively find and print all non-directory files in `folder`.

Answer (score 0):

The way to run commands without having to use absolute path is to use the PATH variable. https://opensource.com/article/17/6/set-path-linux
I.e. add “/home/user” as a component of the PATH variable to run commands in that directory.